# System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger and custom controls with children

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, expression-blend

I have a problem with `System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger`. It works perfectly when my `CustomControl` is a child of some standard WPF panel, but whenever I put it inside my `CustomPanelControl`, the `Tap` event is never subscribed to. If I change the base class of `CustomPanelControl` from `FrameworkElement` to `Panel` then it works. I'm assuming there is something I need to implement, but what?

CustomControl.cs:

```
public class CustomControl: FrameworkElement
{
    public void RaiseTap()
    {
        OnTap();
    }

    protected virtual void OnTap()
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(TapEvent));
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent TapEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CustomControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Tap
    {
        add { AddHandler(TapEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(TapEvent, value); }
    }
}
```

CustomPanelControl.cs:

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class CustomPanelControl: FrameworkElement
{
    public UIElementCollection Children { get; private set; } 

    public CustomPanelControl()
    {
        Children = new UIElementCollection(this, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is a Panel, why not deriving from Panel?

Comment: Because I don't need any of Panel functionality and overhead. I'm using WPF framework to host 3rd party controls that are created via API. I need a container control (Toolbar), which can have children (Buttons, Checkboxes, etc.). All of these controls are not dependant on WPF visuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. For `Children` property to work `GetVisualChild` and `VisualChildrenCount` need to be overridden.

This article proved to be very useful (*A Brief Look at UIElementCollection* section):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24982/Conceptual-Children-A-powerful-new-concept-in-WPF